# Java/Groovy - string: replace characters on matched regex

Tags: java, groovy, scripting

I have a problem with creating regex of match that will get from string example: NotificationGroup_n+En where n are numbers from 1-4 and when let's say i match desired number from range i will replace or remove it with that specific number.

String BEFORE process: NotificationGroup_4+E3

String AFTER process: NotificationGroup_E3

I removed n (number from 1-4) and leave _E with number

My question is how to write regex in string.replace function to match number and than the plus sign and leave out only the string with _En

```
def String string = "Notification_Group_4+E3";
    println(removeChar(string));
}
public static def removeChar(String string) { 
    if ((string.contains("1+"))||(string.contains("2+")||(string.contains("3+"))||(string.contains("4+")))) {
        def stringReplaced = string.replace('4+', "");
        return stringReplaced;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in groovy:

```
def result = "Notification_Group_4+E3".replaceFirst(/_\d\+(.*)/, '_$1')
println result
```

output:

```
~>  groovy solution.groovy
Notification_Group_E3

~>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P8/JTVNoSi1uDSnRMFWQckvvyQzLTM5sSQzPy/evSi/tCDeRNvVWEmvKLUgJzE51S2zqLhEQz8@JiVGW0NPS1NfR0E9XsVQXZOroCgzryQnD2oW1///AA)

A visualization of the regex look like this:

[image: regex visualization]

Regex explanation:

1. we use [groovy slashy strings](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_slashy_string) `/.../` to define the regex. This makes escaping simpler
2. we first match on underscore `_`
3. Then we match on a single digit (0-9) using the predefined character class `\d` [as described in the javadoc for the java Pattern class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef).
4. We then match for one `+` character. We have to escape this with a backslash `\` since `+` without escaping in regular expressions means "one or more" (see [greedy quantifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy) in the javadocs) . We don't want one or more, we want just a single `+` character.
5. We then create a regex capturing group as described in the [logical operators part of the java Pattern regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#logical) using the parens expression `(.*)`. We do this so that we are not locked into the input string ending with `E3`. This way the input string can end in an arbitrary string and the pattern will still work. This essentially says "capture a group and include any character (that is the `.` in regex) any number of times (that is the `*` in regex)" which translates to "just capture the rest of the line, whatever it is".
6. Finally we replace with `_$1`, i.e. just underscore followed by whatever the capturing group captured. The `$1` is a "back reference" to the "first captured group" as documented in, for example, the java [Matcher javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: thank you for support, finally understand regex little bit better, appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try this regex `(\d.*?\+)` [here demo](https://regex101.com/r/ecpo5R/11)

in java :

```
String string = "Notification_Group_4+E3";
System.out.print(string.replaceAll("\\d.*?\\+", ""));
```

output :

```
Notification_Group_E3
```

Comment: This solution helped me a lot, thanks, nice site to test regex

Answer (score 0):

The simple one-liner:

```
String res = 'Notification_Group_4+E3'.replaceAll( /_\d+\+/, '_' )
assert 'Notification_Group_E3' == res
```